# Matching in MongoDB returns unwanted results

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named `flights`. In that collection I have two fields: `origin_country` and the `dest_country`.

These fields just keep record of the origin country and the destination country of a particular flight.

I'm trying to write a query which will return:

- All theinternational flights  **only** (i.e - where the origin and destination countries are different).
- The sum of each (i.e - # of occurences of that flight in the collection).

The problem with the query which I have already is that it's also returning the domestic flights when ran:

*QUERY:*

```
db.flights.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        checking_countries_dont_match: { $ne: ["origin_country", "dest_country"] } 
    } },
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            origin_country: "$origin_country",
            dest_country: "$dest_country"
        },
        "count": {$sum:1}
    } },
    {$sort: {"count":-1} }
])
```

*DOCUMENT SAMPLES:*

```
{
    "_id" : "2675594611",
    "origin_country" : "Germany",
    "dest_country" : "United Arab Emirates",
    "airline_name" : "etihad-airways-etd"
}

{
    "_id" : "2661517182",
    "origin_country" : "Thailand",
    "dest_country" : "Thailand",
    "airline_name" : "nok-air-nok",
}
```

***UPDATE***

I changed the query to the following, but I still get results where the origin and destination are the same:

```
db.flights.aggregate([ 
    { $project: { 
        dont_match: { $ne: ["origin_country", "dest_country"] },          
        origin_country: "$origin_country", 
        dest_country: "$dest_country",
        airline_name: "$airline_name"
    } }, 
    { $match: { 
        airline_name: "etihad-airways-etd",
        dont_match: true
    } },
    { $group: {
        id: {
            origin_country: "$origin_country",
            dest_country: "$dest_country"
        }
    } }
]);
```

***UPDATE 2***

Wokring Query:

```
db.flights.aggregate([ 
    { $project: { 
        dont_match: { $ne: ["$origin_country", "$dest_country"] },          
        origin_country: "$origin_country", 
        dest_country: "$dest_country",
        airline_name: "$airline_name"
    } }, 
    { $match: { 
        airline_name: "etihad-airways-etd",
        dont_match: true
    } },
    { $group: {
        _id: {
            origin_country: "$origin_country",
            dest_country: "$dest_country"
        },
        count: {$sum:1}
    } },
    { $sort: {count:-1}}
]);
```

Thanks for the help everyone :)

Comment: The incorrect usage in `{ $ne: ["origin_country", "dest_country"] }`, it should be `{ $ne: ["$origin_country", "$dest_country"] }`

Comment: Can't believe I missed those, kicking myself now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to modify your query a little bit. Look at this example, should give you an idea:

```
db.flights.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        dont_match: { $ne: ["$origin_country", "$dest_country"] },
        ...
      } 
    },
    {
      $match: {
        dont_match: true
      } 
    },
    ...
]);
```

Comment: check the update to the question. I did what you recommended, but no luck.

Comment: Your structure was right, I just needed to add a bit extra. Check Update #2 if you're interested in the final result. Thanks!

Comment: @D.OSullivan no probs, that's why I left `...` there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below query whether it match your expectation or not:

```
db.flights.aggregate([ 
    { $project: { 
        dont_match: {$cmp: ['$origin_country', '$dest_country']},          
        origin_country: "$origin_country", 
        dest_country: "$dest_country"
    } }, 
    { $match: { dont_match: {$ne: 0} } } 
]);
```

Comment: This would have been another good way of doing it but I got it working. Check update #2 if you're interested in the final working query. Thanks for the help.